# How do I deal with and it is returning ``` HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden?

Tags: python, html, list, dataframe, error-handling

I am trying to copy a table from a website using this code

```
covid = pd.read_html("https://covid19.ncdc.gov.ng/")[0].head()
```

and it is returning

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use requests:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
req=requests.get('https://covid19.ncdc.gov.ng/')
covid = pd.read_html(req.text)[0].head()
'''
|    | States Affected   |   No. of Cases (Lab Confirmed) |   No. of Cases (on admission) |   No. Discharged |   No. of Deaths |
|---:|:------------------|-------------------------------:|------------------------------:|-----------------:|----------------:|
|  0 | Lagos             |                         104187 |                          1044 |           102372 |             771 |
|  1 | FCT               |                          29508 |                            19 |            29240 |             249 |
|  2 | Rivers            |                          18105 |                            27 |            17923 |             155 |
|  3 | Kaduna            |                          11619 |                             1 |            11529 |              89 |
|  4 | Oyo               |                          10352 |                             6 |            10144 |             202 |
'''
```